# What happens when an electric vehicle's battery die?

Tags: battery, electric-vehicle

Common lithium ion batteries seem to have a life span of couple years. Does the same apply to EVs? If so, wouldn't it be costly to replace them (as they tend to be the most expensive part of the vehicle)? If they don't die that easily, what makes those battery different from the ones in common electronics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electric vehicle (EV) batteries have quite an extended lifespan. Many vehicles on the market today have an 8 year/100,000 mile warranty, and even then, the battery useful life is not over. Once the main pack is unable to provide quality performance to the vehicle operator, the pack can be repurposed as home power storage.

Part of the reason that these batteries last longer is they are engineered for very high capacity along with very high current levels for discharge and recharging.

Most of these EV packs have liquid temperature management (Leaf uses air cooling) which is used to keep the pack from overheating during charging and high levels of discharging. I don't know of a laptop with a liquid cooled battery pack. Most laptop owners have experienced the heat of laptop operation if they use it on a lap. The heat does not help prolong the life of that pack.